# Alternative to Blob Object in Javascript

Tags: https, blob, multipartform-data, netsuite

I have to send a `multipart/form-data` request using `Javascript` server-side, I can't use the `Blob` because it's not implemented in the environment I'm working on.

Is there any alternative to `Blob`? I have to send a `pdf file` and I only have its `base64` content.

Thank you

Comment: Add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` to each boundry header and send your base64 string.

Comment: I tried that but it arrives to the server corrupted.

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+fileName+"\"\r\n"+

"Content-type: application/pdf\r\n"+

"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"+

"data:application/pdf;base64,"+fileContent+"\r\n\r\n"+

Comment: You need just the raw base64 (fileContent), the `data:application/pdf,` stuff is just for browsers.

Comment: I tried removing `data:application/pdf,`, also tried removing `data:application/pdf;base64,` but it still not work. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: A Blob is just a binary byte-array when sent over the net. You could try specify its mime with application/binary or application/octet-stream.